# How to push variable change to active canvas draw

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, canvas

I am attempting to change a variable of a js array that draws onto canvas when a specific php session variable is set. The php is being ran in a separate div from the canvas element and js.  The canvas and js are being ran from the main page and the php event occurs in a child element.  I am currently using php to define the variable used in js and when a session is set I want it to update the variable to be displayed in the canvas.

Here is code from the parent page

```
<?php    $colorin = 'rgba(81, 180, 200, 0.5)';    ?>


<script>

'use strict';



var rn = function rn(min, max) {
    return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
};
var ctx = iso.getContext('2d');

var _window = window;
var w = _window.innerWidth;
var h = _window.innerHeight;

var t = 10;
var arr = [];
var cn = 200;
var rad = 300;
var sp = rn(1, 5) / 10000;

iso.width = w;
iso.height = h;

while (~ ~ cn--) {
    var angle = rn(110, 359);

    arr = [].concat(arr, [{
        color: '<?php echo $colorin ?>',
        distortion: rn(15, 75),
        tmod: rn(5, 10),
        size: rn(15, 20),
        speed: 0.0005,
        angle: angle,
        lastPos: {
            x: w / 2,
            y: h / 2
        }
    }]);
}

var draw = function draw() {
    request = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
        return draw();
    });
    t++;

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'source-over';
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0,.1)';
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);

    var crad = rad * Math.sin(300);

    ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
    arr.forEach(function (el) {
        ctx.strokeStyle = el.color;
        ctx.lineWidth = el.size;
        ctx.beginPath();

        var lastPos = el.angle - el.speed;
        var x = w / 2 + (crad + el.distortion * Math.sin(t / el.tmod)) * Math.cos(el.angle * 180 / Math.PI);
        var y = h / 2 + (crad + el.distortion * Math.sin(t / el.tmod)) * Math.sin(el.angle * 180 / Math.PI);

        ctx.moveTo(el.lastPos.x, el.lastPos.y);
        ctx.lineTo(x, y);

        el.lastPos = { x: x, y: y };
        el.angle = (el.angle + 0.0005) % 359;
        ctx.stroke();
    });
};

var resize = function resize() {
    iso.width = w = window.innerWidth;
    iso.height = h = window.innerHeight;
};

var request = requestAnimationFrame(function () {
    return draw();
});
window.addEventListener('resize', function () {
    return resize();
});

</script>
```

and here is the code from the page loaded into a div on the main page.

```
  <?php
    session_start();         

    if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
   $colorin = 'rgba(81, 180, 200, 0.5)';    

    echo "
<script>
                 $(\"#loghold\").hide();   
</script>       
            ";
    }else{ 

      $colorin = 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)';         



  };

      echo "  "; 



 ?>
```

I am unsure how to execute an update of the code since the div is updating but the parent page is obviously not.  I want to update the running js without refreshing or reloading the whole page.

(when the main page is reloaded it does show the desired change)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, PHP is a server-side language, while JavaScript runs in the client's browser. The idea is, PHP can serve parts or whole HTML/CSS/JS parts of your page.

So, having that in mind. As far as I understood, you would like to change a [DOM](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom.asp) element without re-creating the DOM itself. Which means you have 2 options:

1) Either you use [AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) on the client-side to fetch a PHP script served by your Web-Server. PHP script should reply to the AJAX request with a JSON formatted string of Data that you consequently handle in your `success` call-back of the AJAX request.

2) Or you can use WebSockets. A decent explanation example is [here](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/start-using-html5-websockets-today--net-13270).

There probably are other solutions, but these ones are least work-intensive in my opinion. Hope this helps!

**UPDATE:**

So here's what I have for you:

Two files in the web directory - `one.php` and `two.php` .

`one.php`:

```
// Your code from the first block here
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        function checkStuff() {
            $.ajax({
                url:'/two.php',
                type: "POST",
                contentType: "application/json",
                dataType: "json",
                data: "{}",
                success: function(data) {
                    //debugger;
                    var colorin = data.color;
                    // apply colorin
                    var anything = data.anything;
                    // do whatever you want with anything
                },
                error: function(data) {
                    //debugger;
                }
            });
            setTimeout(checkStuff, 3000);
        }
        setTimeout(checkStuff, 3000);
    });
</script>
```

`two.php`:

```
<?php
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['userid'])){
    $userid = $_SESSION['userid'];
    echo $colorin = json_encode([
        'color' => 'rgba(81, 180, 200, 0.5)',
        'anything' => 'helloworld'
    ]);
} else {
    echo $colorin = json_encode([
        'color' => 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
        'anything' => 'anythingYouWant'
    ]);
}
```

So in `one.php` we produce our JS in which we have an AJAX function being executed every 3 seconds and depending on the response, we can do something with the color. Obviously feel free to adapt :)

Comment: You are correct, I want to change a DOM element without recreating the DOM itself.  How would I go about using ajax to update the DOM element, as the DOM is not being recreated?  Would it be adding some ajax type initializer to the start of the script on the DOM to "look" for any "pushes" of code coming from the php elements based in a child div?

Comment: You see, PHP "elements" are not the part of DOM by their nature. PHP parses your .php file and  creates the DOM that you see. So how the whole chain works:
1. User sends request to the "Server" (hosted either locally on developer's machine, or somewhere else).
2. Your Server machine relays the responsibility to handle the request to the Web-Server.
3. Web-Server in turns directs the handling of the request. If PHP script is ran by the command of the Web-Server, then PHP handles the running of the script.
4. PHP outputs what you tell it to output.
5. You see the output in the browser.

Comment: If you use HTML mark-up in the output of your PHP script, then you see HTML mark-up in the browser.
JavaScript (jQuery) is then attached to certain HTML elements (DOM).
So, in order to achieve PHP to JavaScript to DOM manipulation, you will need to use WebSockets. Otherwise, if you want JavaScript to PHP back to JavaScript to DOM manipulation, you can do this with AJAX.
For example, you have a ````<btn id="ask-server"/>```` element. You can execute an AJAX call via "click" event on the button as such: $("#ask-server").on("click", function() { $.ajax({method:"POST",url:"some.php"... }) });

Comment: Refer to the documentation for jQuery's AJAX for properly formulating the request -> http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ 
Keep in mind, that you need to respond back from PHP with JSON and then parse that JSON in $.ajax 's "success" function.
After you have the Data from the server, you can use jQuery to manipulate specific elements. Really, jQuery has a very rich documentation - I would highly advise educating yourself on how it can be used to literally do anything inside the browser.

Comment: I am looking over the documentation now, thank you for the detailed response bds.  I want to clarify though, if I am running js in one div and when a php page is loaded into a separate div it can through ajax/json update the js running in the js div?  Would the ajax be based in the div with the loaded php or in the js div, or both?

Basically when I first started I had the php echoing out the js for the canvas and when the session changed it popped it out again, and when it did this the variables added to the new js.

Comment: Sorry for being persistent with this, but I think it's important to understand the difference. PHP is running on the "remote" server. So PHP is not "loaded into a separate div", PHP is generating ALL of your divs, and only then, browser receives all of the stuff that PHP generated and shows it to you in the browser window - nothing else is done in PHP after the page has been shown. Control is then given to the browser to run JS on the page, and that's where your JavaScript kicks in and starts doing its magic.

Comment: I would recommend the following:
1) Separate your HTML mark-up into one file. Don't use .html extension because you want PHP to parse it, so give it .php extension.
2) Separate your JS code into a separate .js file.
3) Now, simply include your .js file in the .php file from (1) like so: <script src="myscript.js"></script>
4) Now, when you run your .php file, it should work exactly the same as a single PHP script that you have, however, you are getting closer to correct structure.
5) AJAX call should be attached to an "event", either mouse click on a button, or simply timer.

Comment: 6) AJAX is executed from the client's browser, so the declaration for it should be in your .js file. 7) If you wish to have a condition which is handled by the PHP session, then you should create a separate .php file which will check the Inputs received from AJAX call and produce a relevant response, which is then sent back to the user's browser and processed by AJAX success call-back function.
Here is a good guide achieving this precise thing -> http://blog.teamtreehouse.com/beginners-guide-to-ajax-development-with-php

Comment: See the Update to the Answer.

Comment: This works for the question I asked, thank you bds.  It is clear and concise.

Comment: No worries, enjoy :) Glad to be of help!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/115773/discussion-between-leo-frost-and-bds).